# Error using JSON in Android

Tags: android, json, registration

I have a problem with using JSON in doing account registration in my Android application. Here's the problematic part that I found after debugging:

```
// check for login response
                try {
                    if (json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) {
                        registerErrorMsg.setText("");
                        String res = json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS); 
                        if(Integer.parseInt(res) == 1){
                            // user successfully registered
                            // Store user details in SQLite Database
                            DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
                            JSONObject json_user = json.getJSONObject("user");

                            // Clear all previous data in database
                            userFunction.logoutUser(getApplicationContext());
                            db.addUser(json_user.getString(KEY_NAME), json_user.getString(KEY_EMAIL), json.getString(KEY_UID), json_user.getString(KEY_CREATED_AT));                        
                            // Launch Dashboard Screen
                            Intent dashboard = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DashboardActivity.class);
                            // Close all views before launching Dashboard
                            dashboard.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                            startActivity(dashboard);
                            // Close Registration Screen
                            finish();
                        }else{
                            // Error in registration
                            registerErrorMsg.setText("Error occured in registration");
                        }
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Full LogCat:

12-09 14:31:02.360: D/dalvikvm(5339): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 118K, 52% free 2666K/5447K, external 943K/1034K, paused 30ms
12-09 14:31:08.735: W/System.err(5339): java.net.SocketException: Permission denied
12-09 14:31:08.735: W/System.err(5339):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSNetworkSystem.socket(Native Method)
12-09 14:31:08.735: W/System.err(5339):     at dalvik.system.BlockGuard$WrappedNetworkSystem.socket(BlockGuard.java:335)
12-09 14:31:08.740: W/System.err(5339):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.create(PlainSocketImpl.java:216)
12-09 14:31:08.740: W/System.err(5339):     at java.net.Socket.checkOpenAndCreate(Socket.java:821)
12-09 14:31:08.740: W/System.err(5339):     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:967)
12-09 14:31:08.740: W/System.err(5339):     at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:119)
12-09 14:31:08.740: W/System.err(5339):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:156)
12-09 14:31:08.740: W/System.err(5339):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
12-09 14:31:08.740: W/System.err(5339):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
12-09 14:31:08.740: W/System.err(5339):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:359)
12-09 14:31:08.740: W/System.err(5339):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
12-09 14:31:08.740: W/System.err(5339):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
12-09 14:31:08.740: W/System.err(5339):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
12-09 14:31:08.740: W/System.err(5339):     at com.example.musicshare.library.JSONParser.getJSONFromUrl(JSONParser.java:42)
12-09 14:31:08.740: W/System.err(5339):     at com.example.musicshare.library.UserFunctions.registerUser(UserFunctions.java:59)
12-09 14:31:08.740: W/System.err(5339):     at com.example.musicshare.RegisterActivity$1.onClick(RegisterActivity.java:55)
12-09 14:31:08.740: W/System.err(5339):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2538)
12-09 14:31:08.740: W/System.err(5339):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9152)
12-09 14:31:08.740: W/System.err(5339):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
12-09 14:31:08.740: W/System.err(5339):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-09 14:31:08.740: W/System.err(5339):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-09 14:31:08.760: W/System.err(5339):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691)
12-09 14:31:08.760: W/System.err(5339):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-09 14:31:08.760: W/System.err(5339):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
12-09 14:31:08.760: W/System.err(5339):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:847)
12-09 14:31:08.760: W/System.err(5339):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:605)
12-09 14:31:08.760: W/System.err(5339):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-09 14:31:08.760: E/Buffer Error(5339): Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException
12-09 14:31:08.760: E/JSON Parser(5339): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
12-09 14:31:08.760: D/AndroidRuntime(5339): Shutting down VM
12-09 14:31:08.760: W/dalvikvm(5339): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001e578)
12-09 14:31:08.765: E/AndroidRuntime(5339): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-09 14:31:08.765: E/AndroidRuntime(5339): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-09 14:31:08.765: E/AndroidRuntime(5339):     at com.example.musicshare.RegisterActivity$1.onClick(RegisterActivity.java:59)
12-09 14:31:08.765: E/AndroidRuntime(5339):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2538)
12-09 14:31:08.765: E/AndroidRuntime(5339):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9152)
12-09 14:31:08.765: E/AndroidRuntime(5339):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
12-09 14:31:08.765: E/AndroidRuntime(5339):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-09 14:31:08.765: E/AndroidRuntime(5339):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-09 14:31:08.765: E/AndroidRuntime(5339):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691)
12-09 14:31:08.765: E/AndroidRuntime(5339):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-09 14:31:08.765: E/AndroidRuntime(5339):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
12-09 14:31:08.765: E/AndroidRuntime(5339):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:847)
12-09 14:31:08.765: E/AndroidRuntime(5339):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:605)
12-09 14:31:08.765: E/AndroidRuntime(5339):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-09 14:31:08.800: D/dalvikvm(5339): GC_CONCURRENT freed 208K, 51% free 2789K/5639K, external 1350K/1690K, paused 3ms+4ms

So here's MY JSON parsing code:

```
public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url, List<NameValuePair> params) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
            Log.e("JSON", json);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);            
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
}
```

Comment: So what's the problem? I there's an error post your logcat

Comment: where you are using this code?

Comment: @TanjaV updated in a minute

Comment: @ρяσѕρєя K in the registration part

Comment: @AnthonyPangestu : inside AsyncTask's doInBackground method right?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєя K I dont think so. Please refer to my logcat.

Comment: @AnthonyPangestu : ` Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 ` means you have issue in json parsing so post your json string as you have received from server also and your parsing code for more help

Comment: How do I know the received string? Updated in a minute

Comment: @AnthonyPangestu : you can get json string from logcat just search for Log.e("JSON", json); and get string

Comment: @ρяσѕρєя K: No cant find it

Comment: @AnthonyPangestu : post your full log here

Comment: @ρяσѕρєя K updated. Can you please post the answer in answer section?

Answer (score 0):

as log says:

```
java.net.SocketException: Permission denied
```

make sure you have added all required permission including Internet access permission in `AndroidMainfest.xml`:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: @AnthonyPangestu : hi, you have some other issue . ok now problem is solved or not